# Need the attributes labels to show on different lines for SLD

Tags: labeling, style, sld

My SLD is the one below and I need the attributes comp_id to show above auto_area within a circle. Currently they are appearing next to each other and I can't work out how to change it.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Compartment</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#005ce6</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">5 5 1 5</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <TextSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <Geometry>
              <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                <ogc:PropertyName>geometry</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
            </Geometry>
            <Label>
              <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">
                <ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:PropertyName>comp_id</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>                   
                </ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
                  <ogc:Literal>#0.0</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Div>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>auto_calculate_area</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Div>
                </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Function>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Liberation Sans</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">20</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
                <AnchorPoint>
                  <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                  <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>50</Size>
            </Graphic>
            <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="partials">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="graphic-resize">proportional</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="graphic-margin">5</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

As is usually the case a quick search of the manual turns up the [relevant section](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#composing-labels-from-multiple-attributes), "Composing labels from multiple attributes" which points out that as an XML document SLD doesn't care how much or what type of whitespace you use in composing it.

> If you need to add extra white space or newline, you’ll stumble into an XML oddity. The whitespace handling in the Label element is following a XML rule called “collapse”, in which all leading and trailing whitespaces have to be removed, whilst all whitespaces (and newlines) in the middle of the xml element are collapsed into a single whitespace.
>
> So, what if you need to insert a newline or a sequence of two or more spaces between your property names? Enter CDATA. CDATA is a special XML section that has to be returned to the interpreter as-is, without following any whitespace handling rule. So, for example, if you wanted to have the state abbreviation sitting on the next line you’d use the following:

So you need to "hide" the new line from the parser or it will be eaten, making your label come out as (also concatenating is the default behaviour):

```
<Label>
   <ogc:PropertyName>comp_id</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[
]]>
   <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
          <ogc:Literal>#0.0</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Div>
            <ogc:PropertyName>auto_calculate_area</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Div>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
    </Label>
```

And I'm pretty sure you don't need to do a divide by 1.